# Login authentication in Java Swing application

Tags: java, swing, session, authentication, desktop-application

what is the best way to make a 'Login' in my swing application ?

and what is the best way to replace a session (web) in java desktop application ?

i know how to use the login on jsp or php page but how can i do that in swing app ?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Quick google search: https://www.google.com/#q=java%20login

Comment: @JCOC611 sir i want the best way to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with cookie based login session management which you can find easily by goggling it. We use the same for my product.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, for HTTP session based management, I use [Apache HTTPClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/).  This mostly from simplicity from my point of view, but it works well.